# Javascript confusing with terms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

```
var t={a:"1",b:"2"}
```

[image]

is this an `Object` with properties (a,b)

or it is

a `Javascript Labeled Statement` ?

Or does it depends on the context ?

what about this ?

[image]

I was wondering for why Eval wrap itself with `( )`

It is there to resolve confusion. (**statement** vs **expression**)

**Fine.**

But

`{"a":"1"}` can't ever be `Labeled statement` ( because of the `"` which wraps the `a` ) , it is illigle and invalid !!!

so it **Only** be a Object with properties !!!

just as much as
{a:"1"} can only be a Labeled statement and not an object with properties (properties should come with  { **"** a **"**:"1"}

So why Eval cant check it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript confusing terms around eval Checking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157859/javascript-confusing-terms-around-eval-checking)

Comment: @Royi Namir double post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157859/javascript-confusing-terms-around-eval-checking

Comment: I think you are confused with JSON

Comment: @OlegG. No Im not. I know perfectly Good Json. the problem ( if you see Darin Answer) - Is that I thought that properties must come with **"**. That was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var t={a:"1",b:"2"}
```

is an object with properties `a` and `b`.

> what about this ?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../Handler...',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: $.toJSON(jsonObj),
    cache: false,
    ...        
});
```

This is a call to a function called `$.ajax()` and passing an object with properties `type`, `url`, `dataType`, `contentType`, `data`, `cache`, ... as parameter.

> why Eval cant check it ?

Pardon me?

Comment: peroperties should be with **"** ... no?

Comment: @RoyiNamir No, not necessarily in object literal notation.

Comment: @Royi: You must be thinking of JSON. JSON property names should be quoted, JavaScript has no such requirement.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, no, when declaring a javascript object you don't need to put them in quotes. In a JSON string though it is required.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Oh... I thought I have to put " , ( andd thats why i was thinking that - if i have to - wy Eval cant check for it)  - now i see where comes the confusion

Comment: In a JavaScript object literal property names don't need to be quoted _unless_ they have spaces or other "special" characters in them.

Answer (score 2):

It is [JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)](http://www.json.org/) data. In your case, the data is being assigned to a variable.

Fundamentally, JSON is a set of key-value pairs. Take a look at the [JavaScript example](http://www.json.org/js.html) for more clues.

Comment: no it is not since json has to have " at each property ! look at jsonlint

Comment: @RoyiNamir Not necessarily though it is required.

Comment: Actually, the quotes are required for it to be JSON, see sections 2.2 and 2.5 of [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt). JavaScript doesn't require quotes in object literals but JSON does.

Answer (score 0):

These are objects defined using javascript literal notation.

Comment: Again, It's *javascript literal notation*. Also douglas crockford's own JSON RFC states nothing about quoting identifiers http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt

Comment: You have entirely missed the point. The question concerns an excerpt of javascript. That's exactly why I refers to the *literal* notation as being EXACTLY that; LITERAL notation. In this context it makes absolutely no difference if there are single quotes, double quotes or no quotes at all around the name. It is still a LITERAL javascript object. You will notice that I, like many others, included to link to json.org to help explain the the idea of such a notation. If you have a better answer I would encourage you to submit it rather than making unhelpful and pedantic remarks about others.

Comment: I disagree. "Explicitly noting that JSON (and only JSON) requires the quotes" is entirely irrelevant to this question. I'm not accusing anyone of personal attacks. I am responding to the fact that again, you attempted to find fault. This time by criticizing the use of the word *literal*. And again I suggest you could have more constructive input by providing help, rather than criticizing others.